# Sending data from one form to another by TypoScript

Tags: forms, typo3, typoscript

I have problem with sending data from one form to another (using formhandler). I got this two TypoScripts:

On first form:

```
finishers {
    1.class = Finisher_Redirect
    1.config {
        redirectPage = {$formhandlerExamples.multistep-forms.first-step.redirectPage}
    }

  2.class = Tx_Formhandler_Finisher_StoreGP
  2.config {
    get_item = TEXT
    get_item.data = global:HTTP_POST_VARS|first-step|get_item
  }
}
```

And the second one:

```
preProcessors {
  1.class = Tx_Formhandler_PreProcessor_LoadGetPost
    1.config {

  get_item.defaultValue = TEXT
  get_item.defaultvalue.data = global:HTTP_POST_VARS|next-form|get_item

    }
}
```

But nothing happens. Could anyone know why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you have a look in Firebug or similar and post the actual POST request that's sent to the second form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved:

First form TS:

```
finishers {
  10.class = Finisher_StoreGP
  20 {
     class = Finisher_Redirect
     config {
                redirectPage = {$formhandlerExamples.multistep-forms.redirectPage}
            }
     }
  }
```

Second form TS:

```
preProcessors {
   10 {
       class = PreProcessor_LoadDefaultValues
       config {
                1 {
                   get_item.defaultValue = TEXT
                   get_item.defaultValue.data = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|get_item
                  }
               }
        }
}
```